# Configuring ethernet or wifi inernet on centos

Tags: linux, centos

How do i configure ethernet or wifi on laptop, i followed this [tutorial](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/centos-minimal-installation) and my ethernet started properly and still i couldn't receive any packet from ping 8.8.8.8 dns, i have ethernet and wifi on my laptop... same setting on virtual machine works perfectl but on real os it wouldn't work... if i ping

`ping 127.0.0.1`

or

`ping localhost`

what could be the problem???

Answer (score 2):

It could be that your interface is down.

```
ifconfig eth0 up
```

Eth0 is an interface name to get the list of your visible interface type in "ifconfig"

also you should provide us with the list of interface and possibly also hardware

```
dmesg
```

will display the full list of device on your laptop.

Also to be noted some of these command requires root / sudoer.

Wifi : http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Laptops/Wireless